# Is it possible to stream full tweets using Tweepy on_data function

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

Is it possible to return full tweet text within the on_data function when streaming twitter feeds using Tweepy?

I've experimented and seen solutions for the on_status function for streaming. The on_status function can return full texts by doing something along the lines of status.extended_tweet["full_text"]. However this doesn't seem to work for the on_data function and I haven't seen anybody ask this question specifically for on_data (unless I've missed it somehow). So does anybody here know if there are any ways of using on_data to stream full text tweets?

I've seen some people say tweet_mode = 'extended' will work but I've noticed this solution does not apply to streaming tweets.

class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

```
def __init__(self, fetchedFeedsFile):
    self.fetchedFeedsFile = fetchedFeedsFile

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
            print(data)
            with open(self.fetchedFeedsFile, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True

    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

def on_error(self, status):
    if status == 420:
        return False
    print(status)
```

The code I've shown streams tweets using on_data override and outputs tweets however it cannot return full tweets.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the discord server?

Comment: No, which discord server are you talking about? I didn't know there was a discord server for this. I thought it would be nice to put this question here since I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Right on tweepys [main site](http://www.tweepy.org/)

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll give it a try over there (y)

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody have answered my question and I've done some further research and experiment myself. I can confirm that it is possible to fetch full texts using on_data. If anybody ever wants to stream full-sized tweets using on_data you will have to first access the JSON returned by the on_data function. Normally the JSON will contain a string called "text" containing the tweet however if a tweet is too long (over 140 characters I believe? Not sure) there will be a field called "extended_tweet" and within it, a string called "full_text". Below is a snippet of the on_data override I used and it successfully streams full sized tweets to a file.

```
data = json.loads(data)

try:
    tweetStr = data['extended_tweet']['full_text']
except Exception as e:
    tweetStr = data['text']
```

then you can output tweetStr into a print function, file or whatever you want.